# Need an abstract trigger in MySQL 5.1 to update an audit log

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers, audit

I need a way to check for and pass entries into an audit log for any entries in a table that have been changed.  It needs to be abstracted away from the table structure.

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE i_column_name varchar(32);
  DECLARE done INT;
  DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table1';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cursor1;
  REPEAT
    FETCH cursor1 INTO i_column_name;
    IF NOT done THEN

      --pass the variable column_name and its old.i_column_name and new.i_column_name values to the audit table

    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
  CLOSE cursor1;
END$$
```

We have too many tables that need to be audited to custom build every single INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE trigger.  I've tried a number of things and I'm thinking I'm out of luck.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an abstract trigger, it must be defined on a specific table.  The closest you can get is to put the code for the trigger into a stored procedure, and then the triggers for each table will just call the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE audit_update (IN tablename VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  DECLARE  i_column_name varchar(32);
  DECLARE done INT;
  DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = tablename;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cursor1;
  REPEAT
    FETCH cursor1 INTO i_column_name;
    IF NOT done THEN

      --pass the variable column_name and its old.i_column_name and new.i_column_name values to the audit table

    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
  CLOSE cursor1;
END


CREATE TRIGGER table1_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  CALL audit_update('table1');
END
```

You should be able to easily script up something that will create the triggers for all of your tables using the information_schema or something along those lines.

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TRIGGER ', table_name, '_update BEFORE UPDATE ON ', table_name, ...) FROM information_schema...
```

Comment: Ah!  That's a great idea!  We'll fire off a procedure that will build all the triggers.  I'd locked it into my head that there should be a way to do it that I hadn't considered that approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if the answer given would actually work?  How do you access the OLD and NEW values from the trigger inside the stored procedure??

Comment: @Dylan good question.  I'm pretty sure you can't pass OLD and NEW into the procedure, so it's probably not the right solution.  And even if you included all of the code in the trigger (no stored procedure), I'm not sure you can reference the columns like the pseudo-code does anyway (NEW.i_column_name, etc.)