# Create MySQL trigger before update any table

Tags: mysql, triggers, interceptor

I would like to create a trigger that intercepts any update on any table in the database, is there a way to NOT specify the table for which the trigger is being made so it can intercept all updates?

Something like:

```
 create trigger interceptor
 after update on ANY_TABLE
 ....
```

Comment: no, you must declare the trigger table explicitly. but you can reuse the trigger procedure if you write it generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, you have to create individual triggers per table.

However, as the comment above tells, every trigger can be calling the same stored procedure: [Need an abstract trigger in MySQL 5.1 to update an audit log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437000)

You may go even further by creating a procedure that loops through all tables in your DB using `information_schema`, dropping and then (re)creating triggers automatically, then call this script every time you update your DB structure.